# Debug MSE and HTML5 videos in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

In Chrome and Opera there is `media-internals` for getting detailed information on what's going on when a site is about to play a html5 video.

How can I debug video sites in Firefox? (Beside of compiling it from sources and inserting breakpoints)